# Update interface buidler to match constraints

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

In XCode interface builder, when I define some constraints that are different than "current" state of control, there will be **red** lines, now I want to apply constraints and remove red lines, what should I do.
Check attached image, I want to make bottom space in A exactly like what I defined in B, which is 8.[image]

Comment: Possible solution: Add a Height constraint for `Message Details` label and then remove bottom space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Red lines usually mean that you miss some constraints and Xcode doesn't know exactly where to place it (in your case probably a height constraint of the label).

If all constraints are set correctly but the element is at a wrong position it shows an orange rectangle where it belongs to. In that case you can select the element and press `Cmd + alt + =` to move it to it's right spot.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the following notifications appear, if you click on them you have options that will trigger constraints update on the Interface builder. Also on the menu, go to Editor and activate Automatically Refresh Views.

[image]